# count CASE WHEN and count(*) conflict in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, case

Trying to count all records that meet a WHERE condition but also count a subset of those which meet another condition (a case where a column is > 1)

it looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS BOOKINGS#, 
  Count(Case WHEN mNumber > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  MEMBERBOOKINGS
```

My issue is that both columns are returning the same result (which is the smaller result (the case)).

I'm sure it's an easy one but I'm struggling here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `COUNT` with an expression it returns the number of values that are not null and since 0 is not null it will be counted.

In the documentation this is stated as:

> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and
>   returns the number of nonnull values.

(ALL is the default option).

The solution is to change the case expression to either:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN mNumber > 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
-- the else branch is redundant and could be removed, but I wanted to be explicit here.
```

or use `sum` instead:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN mNumber > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: or just `Count(Case WHEN mNumber > 1 THEN 1 END)` because nulls aren't counted

Comment: Great, thanks. knew it would be a silly thing. But now I have an issue where there is some bad data and the mNumber is not always an INT so getting a conversion failed error. Is there a way to ignore anything that is not an INT or to cast it as one to start with? 
Esentially, I just want to count the mNumbers which are 7 numerals in length.

Comment: Got it -  WHEN (LEN(mNumber)=7)
Thanks!

Comment: @Bohemian Indeed. The else branch is redundant.